# How to get all labels for a specific node from neo4j in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, neo4j, neo4jclient

```
MATCH (user:Answer)-[r]->(n) WHERE user.AnsID = 1 RETURN n
```

`MATCH (n) WHERE n.ansid = 2 RETURN labels(n),n`

i want a help to convert these from cypher code to c# query ?

Answer (score 0):

[The Neo4jClient examples](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher-examples) page should be of great help to you.

For your specific queries, these should work:

```
graphClient.Cypher
    .Match("(user:Answer)-[r]-(n)")
    .Where((Answer user) => user.AnsID == 1)
    .Return(user => user.As<Answer>())
    .Results

graphClient.Cypher
    .Match("(user:Answer)")
    .Where((Answer user) => user.AnsID == 2)
    .Return(user => new {
      Labels = user.Labels(),
      N = user.As<Answer>()
    })
    .Results
```

Comment: thanks for helping but actually what i want from this query to return is (n), which is all the labels coming from the selected node (Answer) . if any further explanations are needed i'm here.

Comment: Do the `n` nodes all have a particular label?

Comment: no the n nodes have different labels , in another word the Answer node leads to different labels which i want to return. the Answer nodes leads to either a Question node or a Result node, based on the Answer ID (AnsID) i want to return what is in the other end.

Comment: I think all you'd need to do with the second query is change the `N` from `.As<Answer>()` to `.As<Node<string>>()` you'd then need to parse the `.Data` property of the response to get the type from it - probably using something like `JsonConverter.Deserialize<XX>(N.Data)`